# translate content using where with 2 languages ​​in order (language = "enus" or i18n = "enus")

Tags: php, sql, internationalization

I have a query with subquery to get the translated text, but the where clause not working...
Always returns the text enus because it is the first in the DB even though other languages
How can I do to respect the stated order in the query **(language = "enus" or i18n = "enus")**
firstly ***ptbr*** else or ***enus***

**[translate]**

```
key | language | text
1   | enus     | foo in enus
1   | ptbr     | foo in ptbr
1   | it       | foo in it
```

**[query]**

```
select
    A.*,
    ( select text from translate where key = A.key and (language = "ptbr" or i18n = "enus") limit 1 ) `translate`
from table as A
where A.id = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple `LEFT JOIN` clauses.

```
SELECT a.*, IFNULL(p.text, e.text) AS text
FROM table AS a
LEFT JOIN translate AS p ON p.key = a.key AND p.language = 'ptbr'
LEFT JOIN translate AS e ON e.key = a.key AND e.i18n = 'enus'
```

The subquery that will do what you want is:

```
SELECT text
FROM (SELECT 1 AS priority, text 
      FROM translate
      WHERE key = A.key
      AND language = 'ptbr'
      UNION
      SELECT 2 AS priority, text
      FROM translate
      WHERE key = A.key
      AND i18n = 'enus') x
ORDER BY priority
LIMIT 1
```

Or you could do:

```
SELECT text
FROM translate
WHERE key = A.key
AND (language = "ptbr" or i18n = "enus")
ORDER BY language = "ptbr" DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The general point is that if you want `LIMIT 1` to return a preferred row, you need to use `ORDER BY` to ensure that this row is first in the results.

Comment: I need to be inside the subquery. is possible?

Comment: OK, I've shown how to write your subquery so it does what you want. I'm not sure why you need to do it that way, but if it makes you happy....

Comment: Thanks, I'm testing now ... I have several fields and the main table already has other relationships, I think subquery is best for me that I am beginner

Comment: Bite the bullet and learn how to use JOINs. Otherwise you'll always be a beginner.